# Linux Mint 18.3 KDE black screen after booting when install Nvidia drivers

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, optimus

When I install nvidia drivers after second reboot my screen is black on SDDM (login manager).

Tried to add:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

to file: `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` [from here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#SDDM)

- Nvidia v384
- GeForce GT 525M

Answer (score 1):

After 20 hours of headache, I found the only solution for myself: **replace default SDDM to LightDM**.

On black screen:

1. Ctrl+Alt+F1
2. Login
3. `sudo apt install slick-greeter lightdm lightdm-settings apparmor`
4. Select LightDM
5. `sudo reboot now`

https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3306